# can I make a movable "floating" layer or any other kind of generic floating popup in Acrobat Pro X pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat

Apparently Acrobat supports floating annotations, e.g. sticky note popups and stamp popups (not even sure if there is any difference between these). Since they "float" I can drag them around the screen, even in Reader. But I would like to get a more generalized popup that could display images and other stuff, not just minimally formatted text, so that I could have a draggable image popup. Which is so much cooler than a fixed location image popup achieved using a button or a layer :)

Any thoughts? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a check box in the pop-up's Properties window named "Ensure that pop-ups are visible as the document is scrolled." If selected, when you scroll the PDF page Acrobat will reposition all annotation pop-ups so that they remain visible on your screen.

Comment: thanks for the tidbit. But this does not address my question about how to let me drag popups around with my mouse.

Comment: Using a Flash widget is the only way to implement what you need.